# CNN Backpropagation problems

Tags: java, conv-neural-network, backpropagation

I am trying to write a CNN library from scratch in Java.

The backpropagation algorithm works fine for every layer except the convolution layer itself. I applied the algorithm that is used for the fully connected layer and just updated the kernels by the sum of the derivative.

I created a test network.

```
ConvolutionLayer:
    Input size:           1x4x4
    Kernel size:          1x3x3
    Kernel stride:        1
    Kernel amount:        1
    Kernel offset:        0

    Output size:          1x2x2

ReLU:
    Input size:           1x2x2
    Output size:          1x2x2
    Activation function:  max(0,x)
```

And I did the calculations by hand (I programmed them aswell but to see my mistake I did it on paper)
[image]

So when I applied the backprop `(eta = 1)`. algorithm I calculated the error at the ReLU by taking using this formula:

```
error = (output - expectedOutput) * reluDerivative
```

Then, I calculated the deltas of the kernel for each output neuron of the Convolution Layer. There are 4 kernel deltas displayed because we got 4 output neurons. One kernel delta is calculated by the following formula:

```
delta = error * convolvedInput
```

The 5th kernel delta array is the sum of the kernel deltas. This one is being used for updating the weights (kernel).

The problem now is that every weight is equal or less than 0. This will result in an negative activation map and an overall output of 0 (because of ReLU). This will cause the derivatives at the ReLU to be 0 and this will cause my error at my ReLU to be 0 because of this formula:

```
error = (output - expectedOutput) * reluDerivative
```

So, I guess that I missunderstood something and I am very happy if someone could help me solving my problem.